# which media player to embed in powerpoint pres as touchscreen app?

Tags: powerpoint, media-player, touchscreen

My colleague is creating touchscreen app using POwerpoint 2010. This approach worked so far because a lot can be done by just clicking through menus, setting properties etc, without writing a single line of VBA code.
Now some movie clips must be integrated, and this has shown to be more problematic as expected (for a touchscreen app, that is).

It *is* possible to embed a windows media player as an activex control, however the media control bar is really small, and must be clicked with the pinky finger. Control size cannot be changed, skins do not work in embedded mode (I was told so)

What are viable alternatives? The choices are endless:

- use a different player (VLC for instance but it crashes all the time)
- writing own media control bar  (the volume slider is a problem)
- calling windows media player in standalone mode (the user cannot be prevented to do too much)
- embedding a html page, and this one has something else embedded, a silverlight player for instance.
- embedding a flash player, converting movie clips to a different format before
- embedding a customized solution provided by a powepoint MVP or some other expert

the list goes on and on. I don't have the time to research all of them in depth. What is the most practical alternative? Thanks.

Comment: which version of PowerPoint is being used?

Comment: powerpoint 2010 is being used, see first line of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did: writing own media control bar, based on buttons

To do this, I used a javascript example from the Windows SDK and ported it to VBA. Quite simple.

The volume slider is still a problem, but I found some legacy code samples already.

The progressbar is the only thing visible from the default command bar, everything else has been hidden by an empty shape in the same color as the background color.